# Yii2 Depdrop - TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj ERROR

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown, kartik-v

I'm using Kartik DepDrop widget for dropdown options. I've successfully show the options.

But I got an error in my firebug console like this

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
```

Here is my code:

#### View:

```
<?php
<div class="pib-data-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php echo $form->field($model, 'transaction_type')->dropDownList(PibTransactionType::getOptions(), ['id' => 'parent_id']); ?>

<?=
$form->field($model, 'doc_type')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'options' => ['id' => 'first_child_id'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['parent_id'],
        'placeholder' => 'Select...',
        'url' => Url::to(['pib-data/document-type'])
    ]
]);
?>

<?php
echo FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'file_uploads',
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'doc/*', 'file/*',
        'multiple' => true,
        'enableLabel' => true,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['xls', 'xlsx'],
        'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/pib/pib-data/create']),
    ]
]);
?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php
$this->registerJS("
$('#w1').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    var response = data.response;
    $(location).attr('href', response.url);
}
);", View::POS_END);
```

#### Controller:

```
public function actionDocumentType() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $parent_id = $parents[0];
            $out = PibDocumentType::getOptionsbyTransactionType($parent_id);
            echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);
}
```

#### Model:

**TransactionType.php**

```
public static function getOptions(){
   $data=  static::find()->all();
   $value=(count($data)==0)? [''=>'']: \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id','name');

    return $value;
}
```

**DocumentType.php**

```
public static function getOptionsbyTransactionType($parent_id) {
    $data = static::find()->where(['transaction_type_id'=>$parent_id])->select(['id','name'])->asArray()->all();
    $value = (count($data) == 0) ? ['' => ''] : $data;        
    return $value;
}
```

What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this the smallest example that reproduces your problem? See [mcve].

Comment: @dash2 thanks for the suggestion, I'll update my question soon. Thanks.